# Sitewide search for specific CSS cases

Tags: css

I'm cleaning up the CSS on a fairly large (and somewhat disorganized) website. Is there a simple way (or a piece of software) that will let me find, for example, all the "a" tags that are within "h3" tags?  Or all the "spans" that are within "p" tags?  I want to modify some of these CSS rules but I'm afraid I'll break something hidden somewhere.  Any advice?

Comment: Are these static webpages, or are they dynamically generated?  (i.e. Are you looking at the source or the output?)

Comment: They're static smarty templates.

Answer (score 1):

You could just modify your CSS to highlight the elements you are looking for. For example

> `h3 a { background-color: red }`

will highlight all the "a" tags that are within "h3" tags.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to want to take a look at [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [XPathChecker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095), two excellent Firefox extensions.

Comment: I do use firefox but I just looked into it further and discovered the command line API - thanks!  But as far as I can tell this only works on a single page at a time.  Is there a way to make it search an entire site (ie, recursive folders)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to clean up the CSS on a website, I highly suggest the [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/) plugin [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392), which is specifically designed to scan websites for CSS that is going unused.  It can even scan multiple pages at a time, either by having it automatically spider your website or by providing it a sitemap file of the specific pages you want checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a command line tool called Element Finder which lets you enter in a CSS selector, like "h3 a", and then searches through the directory and finds all of the HTML files with elements matching that selector.

You will need to install Element Finder, cd into the directory you want to search, and then run:

```
elfinder -s "h3 a"
```

Or:

```
elfinder -s "p span"
```

For more info please see http://keegan.st/2012/06/03/find-in-files-with-css-selectors/